# Make Vim ignore syntax highlight only for long lines

Tags: vim, highlight

Recently I found out that long lines in Vim take forever to redraw, and even can give you error:

`E363: pattern uses more memory than 'maxmempattern'`

or

`'redrawtime' exceeded syntax highlighting disabled`

Increasing those values make things even worse… So I though of more efficient way to solve this problem, ignoring syntax highlight for only those long lines will be enough.

So can this be done in Vim: `Ignore highlight only for long lines`, e.g. skip highlighting for those lines?

Comment: See `:help 'synmaxcol'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was causing such slowdown - it was caused by `php` syntax from `vim-polyglot` plug-in, fixed it by disabling `php` through `let g:polyglot_disabled = ['php']`.

Answer (score 2):

add the following line to your .vimrc file:

```
set re=0
```

Comment: That might help if it wasn't set to default for me which is: (help)`'regexpengine' 're' number (default 0)`

Comment: I looked up the setting to figure out why it was better to set `set re=0` and I came across https://jameschambers.co.uk/vim-typescript-slow and narrows in on someone else who's run into this issue at https://github.com/HerringtonDarkholme/yats.vim#config

----
The tl;dr is you have to run `set re=0` in your .vimrc because I think it forces it to use the latest regexengine which is otherwise super slow for syntaxes like `typescript`